# numpy: filling a subset of array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array of dimension 3x3 i.e. it has a total of 9 elements. I have 8 values that I would like to set and the value at location (2, 2) will always be 1. I can do it individually as follows:

```
import numpy as np
def set(coefs):
    a = np.zeros(3,3)
    a[0, 0] = coefs[0]
    a[0, 1] = coefs[1]
    a[0, 2] = coefs[2]
    a[1, 0] = coefs[3]

    ...
    a[2, 2] = 1
```

However, I was wondering if there is a more concise and general way to fill those 8 values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like

```
np.array(coefs[:8]+[1]).reshape((3,3))
```

should do exactly what you require, right?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks. I am still getting used to these funky python addressing!

Comment: Ciao @Luca, this is more numpy 2-d addressing than Python addressing per se:-).  Anyway, please make sure to **accept** this answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to the left of the A) once enough time has elapsed for acceptance (I can never recall how long you must wait before accepting depending on your rep:-).

Comment: I have to wait 10 minutes before accepting the answer ;-) You were too fast :)

Comment: @Luca, scusami, this community's so awesome that unless I answer at once I'll never get accepts!-)